# Why can I not make a cell have the accessibility trait "Button"?

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, accessibility

In Xcode 8.0 using a storyboard I am trying to assign a cell in my tableview the accessibility trait "Button" (this cell already has the trait "User Interaction Enabled"). But, when I try to check off the box beside "Button" I am briefly shown a '-' character and the box refuses to be checked. Why is this and how can I assign the "Button" trait to this cell?

Comment: were you able to figure out anything ? Kinda stuck in the same situation !

Comment: @GoodSp33d I wasn't :( Had to set in manually in the code

Comment: found another similar question, turns out all you had to do was restart Xcode. But the bug can re appear again. Its a bummer that they have not fixed it yet !